# Base64 encoded images do not appear on outlook web and mobile app, but appear in desktop app

Tags: html, .net, outlook, base64, office365

I am sending set of outlook emails with base64 encoded images added to mail body. In the desktop application of mine and the other receiver, we can see all the images in the mail body. But, when it comes to the web and mobile app, images on some of the mails do not appear. No matter how many time I send, these do not appear on the web.

What i am adding is a tables in excel file saved as a .jpg file using uipath activities, encoding them in base 64 and embedding into mail body using below tag. When the number of row in the table reduces, these images appear perfectly in all three (desktop app, web and mobile).

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64, /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAeAB"/>
```

Using below method to encode image to base64.

```
Dim imageArray As Byte() = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(ImagePath)
Base64ImageRepresentation  = Convert.ToBase64String(imageArray)
```

When I inspect these elements on browser this what I get.

[image]
This is what appears on the web. The table under the text is missing. It contains a around 10-15 rows. Tables below contains only 3 rows. Then it appears. But, when the table below also contains around 20-30 rows, both tables are missing.

[image]

What could be the reason for this issue. The problem is it appears on the desktop application although it doesn't appear on web.

Appreciate, if I can have some help to find a solution to this issue.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have it backwards? Desktop version of Outlook does not support embedded base64 images since the rendering is performed by Word. Web and mobile versions should be fine.

Comment: Well, what you said was what I also thought earlier, but what happened was other way. Anyway, I changed the approach to use cid: method instead of base64. Now it appear in both desktop and web.